# pbviz start : Permission denied 0.0.0.0:8080 - Power BI Custom Visuals

Tags: permissions, powerbi, pbiviz

Clearly, I'm new to this, I am trying to create my own visuals for a Power BI report. In order to do that  I must follow the following tutorial:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sarahsays/creating-new-power-bi-custom-visuals/

Every time I try to run the newly created project I received the error mentioned below related to permission as far as I can see

I uninstalled then re-installed Node and Power BI Custom Visual tool, I tried to play with the proxy server but no use.

```
PS C:\PBITEST\PBI\visio> pbiviz start

info   Starting server...
info   Start preparing plugin template
```

> pbiviz : (node:18356) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + pbiviz start
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ((node:18356) De....hooks` instead:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError 
>   events.js:174
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event^
>   Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8080 at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1262:19) at list
>   enInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
>       at Server.listen (net.js:1414:7)
>       at Server.listen (C:\Users\Hicham\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\powerbi-visuals-tools\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:744:30) at WebPackWrap.applyWebpackConfig.then (C:\Users\Hicham\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\powerbi-visuals-tools\bin\pbiviz-start.js:109:24)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at emitErrorNT (net.js:1306:8)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

It is expected that when this runs successfully the server should be listening to Port `8080` but instead, I get the code above.

Comment: Are you sure that another application didn't hold port 8080?